# VB .NET and I want the Username and password to come from the database and for the program to close after 3 fail attempts

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
Private Sub LogReceptionist()
  
     Dim Username() As String = {"Paul", "Philip", "James"}
     Dim Password() As String = {"1234", "12345", "123456"}
```

I don't want the Username and Password to  be like the one above instead I want the Username and
Password to come from the SQL Database like this:

```vb
 Username = "select * from ReceptionistTbl where RecepName='" & txtUsername.Text & "'"
       
 Password = "select * from ReceptionistTbl where password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
```

I also want to make the program to close after 3 failed login attempts from the user. Everything is working but it is just that I'm not able to make the Username and Password check come directly from the database.

```
    Dim attempts As Integer = 0
    Dim Travel As New PatientForm

    Do While (attempts <= 3)
        attempts = attempts + 1
        Password.Contains(txtPassword.Text)
        Username.Contains(txtUsername.Text)

        If (Username.Contains(txtUsername.Text) And Password.Contains(txtPassword.Text) And Array.IndexOf(Username, txtUsername.Text) =
                Array.IndexOf(Password, txtPassword.Text)) Then

            Travel.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            txtUsername.Clear()
            txtPassword.Clear()

        Else
            txtUsername.Clear()
            txtUsername.Focus()
            txtPassword.Clear()
        End If
    Loop

    Checkers += 1

    If Checkers = 3 Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, your method of getting the username and password is *wide* open to injection. **Parametrise** your statements.

Comment: `"password='" & txtPassword.Text` also **strongly** implies you are storing plain text passwords; a huge security problem. *Always* hash and salt your passwords and store *those* values in the DBMS. **NEVER** store plain text passwords.

Comment: See [why parameters are a best practice](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/).

Comment: Looks I don't need a login to use your app, I just need to enter my name as `'='`

Comment: Once you've hashed your password, there is no need to even select back the hash. Just pass through the hash of the entered password, compare it server-side and return a yes/no result. What is your actual question?

Comment: You should read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?499888).

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve data from Sql Server? Before you can retrieve data you must connect to the database. Start your research there. How to connect to Sql Server with ADO.net.